# Gap between DIV

Tags: html, css

I have a content div that surrounds all my content, a navigation div and I have made a div for nivo slider, however, the divs after the nivo slider have a gap between them and I am wondering if anyone here can assist me? The site is: http://alumnistatus.cloudapp.net/.

[image]

Comment: what are we looking at? where are the gaps you talk of?

Comment: Seeing your code would be helpful …

Comment: Graphic designers choice, but thank you.

Comment: Sorry I was not more specific. The gap I am speaking of is between the green div and the white content below it (it is only green so the div is obvious - won't be left that way)

Comment: The green div is the nivo slider holder. it will be placed there later

Comment: Without code we can't help you. Please copy the relevant code or give us a URL.

Comment: @AsherPeterRankin - Most of the time these evil gaps are because of the `margin`. You should set everything by default to `margin: 0px`.

Comment: @kay the url is alumnistatus.cloudapp.net

Comment: Are you using a reset CSS? Are your divs set as inline-block?

Comment: @AsherPeterRankin, [the page does not load](http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/alumnistatus.cloudapp.net).

Comment: Sorry, I'm still a bit confused. Are you referring to the grey line under the green box?

Comment: @robertsmith it's a .net default CSS for the customer portal plugin for CRM. I have made modifications to the base.css file

Comment: @kay sorry, it is just a very slow server. It will load eventually.

Comment: @derek thank you. I will investigate that and see if it makes any difference

Comment: @AsherPeterRankin - [The server is not reachable.](http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&u=alumnistatus.cloudapp.net&act=url)

Comment: I checked your site and looked into your code. I couldn't find what caused the problem, but what is up with the -10000px margins/paddings?

Comment: @AsherPeterRankin, I took a look at the site and didn't see the issue you seem to be having. What browsers does it seem to happen on? [Screenshot](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/513/examplez.png/) Also, it would be helpful if you could post any related HTML or CSS you have. It seems a lot of people are having difficulty reaching your site.

Comment: I see the issue but I don't see what is causing it. What I do see is some bad code in your header it renders source as         <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/css/

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/combo?2.8.0r4/build/assets/skins/sam/skin.css" />
 notice that the link is not closed before the next one is started. That will cause browsers to gulp.

Comment: @luudjacobs good question. It's there by default in the Microsoft customer portal. I've removed them now and will see if that makes a change.

Comment: @sdjuan Thank you very much for noticing that. :) I am currently redeploying with these changes and will see if it fixes it.

Comment: Unfortunately the issue still remains.

Comment: Without your code ( the CSS and HTML) this question is not useful to anyone, especially when the website you linked to changes its markup or CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The paragraph "test nivo content" is adding `margin-bottom` to the green box.  If you add `margin-bottom:0` to that paragraph, it removes that space in Chrome.